# SugarCRM How to allow different postal addresses

Tags: sugarcrm, street-address

(first of all, i'm sorry for my english, it's not my native language)
I am a new SugarCrm user and I try to do the most i can with the Graphic Interface.

**My Version** 
I'm running Sugarcrm CE 6.5.4 on linux.

**What I want to do :**

**1]** For each accounts(or company) the user creates, i would like to make possible a creation of different addresses (postal addresses) :
- A primary address (only one, related to only one account)
- A Billing address (only one, related to only one account)
- A delivery address (maybe several, but related to one sale -which is related to one account)
- An exploitation address (maybe several, but related to one sale -which is related to one account)

**2]** I would like to propose a type's choice (with i.e a Dropdown list - Which i know how to create one new)
BUT when the user has already created a primary or billing address, when he creates a new address, the list don't show the choice "Primary" or "Billing" (because he can only create one of each by account)

**3]** I would like to propose a little button + or - to add or remove an address (like it is made for email - premary...)

**4]** I would like the all thing to be displayed like the "Billing - Address" (or "Delivery - Address").

I'm totally lost in all these things i want to do and don't know by what i can start...

**My Questions :**
- Do i have to create a module?
- Can i create it with the Interface?
- if yes, How? (by Module Builder, I guess, but which relations, what can i do in this module... ?)
- How do i do the relations in the Data-base? Does it make it itself?
- All has to be done very quickly, so is it easy to do?(i mean, even if we are totally dumb and beginner?)

Thank you for your time, and thank you by advance for your response.

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add some address fields through the Studio because it's a "type" o field available in field type list

Comment: I will test it after noon and come back if it's not what i want to do/if i run some bugs, but already, thanks for your response! :)